# перевернуть каждое слово в строке

Tags: javascript

пишу функцию которая переворачивает все слова но порядок слов остаётся прежний:

> reverseWords("This is an example!"); // returns  "sihT si na !elpmaxe"

мой код:

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  // Go for it
  return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

reverseWords("This is an example!");
```

> у меня получается так: "!elpmaxe na si sihT" а нужно сохранить порядок, как?

Comment: `split` в массив. Перебираем массив и для каждого элемента делаем `reverse`. Потом клеим обратно массив через пробел. Все.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function reverseWords(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map(
            function(a) {return a.split("").reverse().join("")}
           ).join(" ");
}
```

Сначала разбиваем на слова, потом для каждого слова разбиваем на буквы и разворачиваем, потом все это опять объединяем

Comment: у меня не получается  добавить ваш код к себе в функцию

Comment: @stas0k Как не получается `return str.мой_код`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  
  str = str.split(" ");
  
  var res = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      res.push (str[i].split("").reverse().join(""));  
  }  
  
  return res.join(" ");
}

console.log(reverseWords("This is an example!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// es6
const reverseWords = (str) => str
    .split(' ')
    .map( word => word.split('').reverse().join('') )
    .join(' ');

reverseWords('This is an example!');
```